# I need to give an alert when the user places the cursor in a textbox in asp.net. How do I go about doing this?

Tags: asp.net, textbox, alert, onfocus

I need to give a custom alert to the user when the user places the cursor in a textbox item in asp.net. How do I go about doing this? 
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript on focus event.

On Page_Load or Page_Init method add this code:

```
 mytextBox.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "enterTextBox();")
```

Then on the page add a script tag with this :

```
function enterTextBox() {
     alert('hello');
}
```

Comment: I also have enable and disable textbox. So when the textbox is disabled I dont want the alert to fire. So do I need to do the remove attribute?

Comment: onfocus and onblur don't fire if a textbox is disabled.

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" onfocus="alert('Got focus!');"/>
```

or a bit more involved:

```
<script>
  function InputFocus()
  {
    var inp = document.getElementById('myInput');
    inp.onfocus = null; 
    alert('Got focus - ' + inp.id);
    setTimeout(function() { inp.onfocus = InputFocus; }, 100);
  }
</script>

<input type="text" value="one"/>
<input id="myInput" type="text" onfocus="InputFocus();" value="two"/>
<input type="text" value="three"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

the two events that you need are onfocus (elemant has focus and can accept input) and onblur which gets fired when leaving the element (say a text box). Disabled elements cannot have focus so these events will not occur in that case.